# Push existing image to another registry (without mounting docker.sock or using docker:dind)

Tags: docker

Is it actually posible to push the existing image to another docker registry without either mounting docker.sock or starting docker:dind?

I'm running docker build in cluster (with kaniko) and the image needs to be pushed to another repository.
I haven't found an option for kaniko to do that. The only way would be to start a new build (am I correct?).

Is there another alternative? Pulling and pushing should be actually easier as building, and should not require access to the docker daemon?

Comment: what about pulling the image from the default registry and manually pushing to another registry? One can login in any registry as long as they have credentials

Comment: @Petronella this is exactly what I'm attempting to do, but docker command require docker.sock or docker:dind when run in cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker registry has a [documented API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/), and OCI is close to finishing their [distribution-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec) release, so it's possible to interact with the registry directly rather than using the docker engine. I've been doing exactly that with [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) that includes a `regctl image copy` command that likely does exactly what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: That regclient looks very interesting, but it's terribly underdocumented, for example I can't find a single example for how to use registry login...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo thanks for the feedback. More documentation is definitely on my todo. Each command does have a `--help` page that lists options that may help. E.g. `regctl registry login --help`

Comment: I was able to retag withing one repository and push to another non-protected repository, but I've failed to push to another protected repository. Docker tag ... docker push works on the dev machine, on the same machine regctl fails..."All requests failed".
Debug says 'withAuth=false' so apparently the authorization is not used"

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Might be easiest to open an [issue on regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient/issues) with steps to reproduce and output you're seeing.